# jQuery Slider to php script: issue handling "0" values

Tags: php, jquery, string, jquery-ui-slider

I am using the jQuery slider component in one of my forms as follows:

```
<form action="survey_dis.php" method="POST" target="_self" name="apForm">
<div data-role="rangeslider">
<input type="range" name="F1" id="F1" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="" onchange='document.getElementById("bar1").value =  document.getElementById("F1").value."%";'>
<input type="text" name="bar1" id="bar1" value="" size="3" disabled />
</div>
(...)
</form>
```

As you note, the allowed range should indicate percent, so the allowed values have to be between 0 and 100. Because a check of empty($var) will return TRUE even for "0", I've defaulted "value" with an empty string...

Now in my php script, I need to check whether the user has actually selected a value instead of keeping it at the default:

```
for ($i=1; $i<51; $i++){ // 51 questions
    if (isset($_POST["F$i"]) && strlen($_POST["F$i"]) && ($_POST["F$i"]<>'-1') ){
        $F_var = $_POST["F$i"];
    } else {
        print "Question # $i missing";
        $missing_fields += 1;
    }
}
```

However, it always looks to php as if a slider selection has been made and the "else" condition never applies... even if I default "value" with "0".

Comment: if you ar needing to expand the variable $i you need it outside of the quotes. "F" . $i

Comment: Even if the onchange event doesn't fire it is looking like a slider selection has been made?

Comment: @Chris if evaluates fine.

Comment: @ArthurSwails yes, the "else" condition never fires...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have a syntax error in your `onchange`. Your `%` is concatenated with a `.` instead of a `+`

`document.getElementById("F1").value + "%";'`

**Why does the value 0 return true?**

You check the string length of it, which is 1, even for a `0`. The other two conditions are of course also true, since `0 != -1` and the given parameter is set.

You could send `bar` fields instead and check them as they are on default empty. **Note:** to do this the field cannot be `disabled` as it would be never send in this case. You could set it to `readonly` for example.

**Hint:** You start your for loop at `$i=1`. So your last question will never be checked, as you stop looping on `$i<51` instead of `$i<=51`

Comment: Thanks! All those syntax errors you mentioned were just in the demo code (to remove all the clutter, unfortunately, I seem to have a problem copying & pasting x-))  It works fine with
    if (isset($_POST["bar$i"]) && strlen($_POST["bar$i"])){   $F_var = $_POST["F$i"];
}else{ $missing_fields++; } 
now.